# 2 foreign keys from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, netbeans

So I'm trying to create a Online Pizza Order System. My question is when creating table for delivery guy, should I use **only** cust_id in delivery guy table or I should also include **cust_address**

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
    cust_id varchar(7) not null,
    cust_name varchar(30) not null,
    cust_address varchar(40) not null,
    cust_num varchar(11) not null,
    order_id int,
    primary key(cust_id)


);

CREATE TABLE Delivery_Boy
(
    employee_id varchar(7) not null,
    cust_id varchar(7) not null,
    order_id int,
    primary key(employee_id),
    foreign key(order_id) references PIZZA_ORDER(order_id),
    foreign key (cust_id) REFERENCES Customer(cust_id)
);
```

Comment: If you give Delivery_Boy the cust_address it looks like the address belongs to the Delivery_Boy instead of Customer so I would go with what Jay Shankar Gupta said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only `cust_id` is enough you can get `cust_address` by joining both table using `cust_id`.

Like This

```
SELECT DB.cust_id,C.cust_name,C.cust_address,C.cust_num,C.order_id
FROM CUSTOMER C INNER JOIN Delivery_Boy DB
ON C.cust_id = DB.cust_id
```